# Unity - How to make a procedurally generated texture not pixelated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I am using procedural world generation in my Unity game, I would like to make the texture on it not pixelated but the tutorial I'm following doesn't show how to fix that. I tried googling it but no one else seems to know how to fix it.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

But how can I make it look like:

[image]

Links:

[Code](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vr7x2eumu3phf75/Project.unitypackage/file)

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FilterMode.html

Comment: those filter modes don't really help that much all they do is blur the pixels, but you can still see them.

Comment: Use a smaller grid? Not sure what you're looking for here, you didn't post a pic of what you've got or any explanation of what's wrong other than its pixelated.

Comment: @Chuck [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N_t916iJsC7UazvYrEwF3pFhC3u3izwX/view?usp=share_link) is an image of what it looks like for me and above i linked an image of what i want it to look like

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have my entire project files on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I learned how to use shader graphs and that fixed it for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Divide the mesh into an X, so the existing four corners and the middle, and then color each wedge (North, East, South, and West) based on neighbor matching. If neighbors on two adjacent sides share a type (like North and East are both grass) then those corresponding wedges get the same texture as the neighbor.

Right now everything looks pixelated because you're drawing everything as squares.

You could make some transitional textures to apply in the wedges to look really good, and then those would only matter based on individual neighbors.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Unity so i don't know how to divide the mesh into an X